# finding the resources consumed by a single connection to the database

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, cpu, ram

Usually databases(focusing `postgres`) offer multiple simultaneous connection that enable us to perform CRUD operations on them. I wonder if each connection is resource heavy, and would like to know if there is a measure as to how much resource (cpu/ram etc) each connection keeps consumed/allocated while the connection is active?

Any tool or methodology to help monitor this would be great

Comment: That depends entirely on what the connection is currently doing and how you configured parameters like `work_mem` and `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`.

Comment: do you know of any tool or methodology to help monitor this?

Comment: You don't need to monitor each individual connection. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe , I was thinking of keeping a connection for prolonged period of time especially implementing multitenant system, so I am wondering if that would cause issue because my connections would increase over time , so I'd like to monitor the resource consumption for an open connection in it's ideal state

Comment: You should use a connection pool of limited size. That is the canonical solution to this problem.